# Type inference on abstract type member

Tags: scala, generics

```
val s1: ({type T <: String})#T = "some string" // failed

val s2: ({type T = String})#T = "some string" // compiled
```

Why first line failed to compile? Why `T` can't be a string there?

**Edit:**

Simplified case without lambdas.(*Not sure if that is exactly the same from type system perspective*)

```
trait K {
  type T <: String
  val s1:T = "some string" // failed
}
```

**Edit 2 :**

one more case

```
type  K  = {type T <: String}

val s1:K#T = "some string" // failed

def test(in: K#T):K#T = in // can be used as output type as well
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`k.T` is a [path-dependent type](https://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/13/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-13-path-dependent-types.html). It can be different for every instance `k` of `K`.

```
trait K {
  type T <: String
  val s1: T /*= "some string"*/
}

object K1 extends K {
  override type T = Null
  override val s1 = null
}

object K2 extends K {
  override type T = Nothing
  override val s1 = ???
}

object K3 extends K {
  override type T = String with Int
  override val s1 = ???
}


object K4 extends K {
  override type T = shapeless.Witness.`"some other string"`.T
  override val s1 = "some other string"
}

object K5 extends K {
  // K5.T is abstract
  override val s1 = ???
}

object K6 extends K {
  // K6.T is abstract but different from K5.T
  override val s1 = ???
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe it has to do with the variance relationship to the return (result) type.

Notice that `T` is accepted as an input `String` ...

```
def s3[T <: String](s:T) = "some string" // T as input
s3("blah")  //input T = String
```

... but not as an output `String`.

```
def s3[T <: String](s:T):T = "some string" // fails to compile
//                      ^^^
```

But reverse the `T`-to-`String` relationship and this works ...

```
def s3[T >: String](s:T):T = "some string" // T as input and output
s3("blah")
```

... and so does this.

```
val s1: ({type T >: String})#T = "some string" // good
```

Comment: regarding input:  def tt(t: ({type T <: String})#T) =null . Not working even as input. You can't pass a string as a parameter.

Comment: and btw T <: String can be used in return type:  def s3[T <: String](s:T):T = s . The problem in your example is that we can't guaranty that T is a exactly String. It can be singleton type (s.type) for example.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not that `T` can't be a string, but that it can potentially be something else, to which a string can't be assigned (e.g. `Null` or `Nothing`).

Comment: but when I'm doing something like this:       def tt[T <: String] (t: T ) =null it works (can pass string as a parameter). I still have T that can be potentially assigned to Null. On the other hand this doesn't work again:  def tt(t: ({type T <: String})#T) =null

Comment: shouldn't T be just inferred to String?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. `T` isn't a type parameter here, it doesn't make sense to infer it.